# Installation of CDK fails when running the CDS-installer

Tags: redhat-containers

As I want to get a bit of exposure to OpenShift, I decided to install the CDK on my machine. According to the documentation I started the installation. Everything is fine, but the CDK download/install fails.
Here are the lines from the log file:

```
Wed, 26 Jul 2017 07:52:20 GMT-ERROR: cdk failed to download: SHA256 checksum 
verification failed
Wed, 26 Jul 2017 07:52:26 GMT-INFO: Restarting download
Wed, 26 Jul 2017 07:52:28 GMT-Configured 
file='C:\Users\ALEXAN~1.MEN\AppData\Local\Temp\minishift_3_0_0_GA.exe' 
sha256='4f51b5b6bc8fc93bda5d25f5f58f213a8165b6c0e0f2b77dbb53ae6da4966068'
Wed, 26 Jul 2017 07:52:28 GMT-ERROR: cdk failed to download: SHA256 checksum     
verification failed
Wed, 26 Jul 2017 07:52:34 GMT-INFO: Restarting download
Wed, 26 Jul 2017 07:52:36 GMT-Configured 
file='C:\Users\ALEXAN~1.MEN\AppData\Local\Temp\minishift_3_0_0_GA.exe' 
sha256='4f51b5b6bc8fc93bda5d25f5f58f213a8165b6c0e0f2b77dbb53ae6da4966068'
Wed, 26 Jul 2017 07:52:36 GMT-ERROR: cdk failed to download: SHA256 checksum 
verification failed
Wed, 26 Jul 2017 07:52:38 GMT-INFO: Restarting download
```

So I am grateful for any ideas what I am doing wrong.
Alternatively, how I can install the CDK manually.

I am running on a Win 10 machine with 16 GB memory, have Oracle JDK 1.8 installed and put the install below "Documents" as an installation in the C root will not work (IT sec restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

It works now. maybe there was something wrong yesterday.